# What is this area called in UI/UX?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, web-app, design, component

My web designer has made a new design for the listing page. I'm going to ask him to do a few changes but I'm wondering what is the area in the red box called in UI/UX? What should I call it when referring to it? "Hotel box" and "Hotel widget" came to my mind but is there a technical word for this kind of element?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a card. Its present on several design languages. Check out material for example: https://material.io/components/cards

Comment: Ask your designer what it is called. It is important to have a common/shared language for communication design in every project.

Comment: I think @musefan has a valid point. Even though this is not answering your question, but yes, you should ask your designer. Design is a interdisciplinary job that should go hand in hand in every part of your company. From the concierge to the account manager over the design team up to the company owner. Design is made for humans, not for designers, that's why most designers value input (even if it is just a question) that comes from non-designer.

Comment: @NickLeBlanc thank you for your reply. I'll check out the material design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is called a "Card".
It is used to as a compound for multiple elements that belong to one display or meaning.

Design parts are usually UI terms. UI is the User Interface while UX is the User Experience.

UI is visual, UX is theoretical meaning behind the UI.

To find out more about "Cards" feel free to check out more here:

- [UI-Patterns: Cards](https://ui-patterns.com/patterns/cards)
- [Justinmind: Cards](https://www.justinmind.com/blog/cards-ui-design/)

Here are some Design Systems that use UI Cards:

- [Material Design](https://material.io/components/cards)
- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)
- [Cirrus](https://spiderpig86.github.io/Cirrus/#cards)

Comment: Marvinpoo, thank you so much for your detailed reply. I'll definitely check out that links.

Answer (score 1):

It called card layout, It's a combination of multiple UI element to represent your item list. Think about any eCommerce site and their item display.

Comment: Ananta Bose, thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire area in red is clickable maybe except the favorite icon, I would call it HotelCard or PropertyCard.

I would assume a widget would be ideal if this is a dismissable card or something the user can add or remove at their own will.

Comment: I think you're being a bit too specific. If the area showed recipe cards?  Yes. If it's a team collaborating together, but no if it's a general UX term. By the way - I don't know of a specific term.

Comment: John Iseghohi, thank you very much for your reply.